# huggingface transformer with tensorflow saves two files as model weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, huggingface-transformers

This is how I build the model for classification task:

```
    def bert_for_classification(transformer_model_name, max_sequence_length, num_labels):
        config = ElectraConfig.from_pretrained(
            transformer_model_name,
            num_labels=num_labels,
            output_hidden_states=False,
            output_attentions=False
        )
        model = TFElectraForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(transformer_model_name, config=config)
        # This is the input for the tokens themselves(words from the dataset after encoding):
        input_ids = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_sequence_length,), dtype=tf.int32, name='input_ids')

        # attention_mask - is a binary mask which tells BERT which tokens to attend and which not to attend.
        # Encoder will add the 0 tokens to the some sequence which smaller than MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,
        # and attention_mask, in this case, tells BERT where is the token from the original data and where is 0 pad
        # token:
        attention_mask = tf.keras.layers.Input((max_sequence_length,), dtype=tf.int32, name='attention_mask')

        # Use previous inputs as BERT inputs:
        output = model([input_ids, attention_mask])[0]
        output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_labels, activation='softmax')(output)
        model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[input_ids, attention_mask], outputs=output)

        model.compile(loss=keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
                      optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(3e-05, epsilon=1e-08),
                      metrics=['accuracy'])

        return model
```

After I trained this model I save it using `model.save_weights('model.hd5')`
But it turns out there are two files that are saved: `model.hd5.index` and `model.hd5.data-00000-of-00001`

How should I load this model from the disk?

Comment: Have you installed hd5py package?

Comment: @Kaveh yes I have installed `h5py` already

Comment: Oh. You wrote the extension `hd5` while it is `h5`. `model.save_weights('model.h5')`, if it is not in `h5` format, it will save in `SavedModel` format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 possibilities to save a model, either in keras `h5` format or in tensorflow `SavedModel` format.

You can determine the format by passing the `save_format` argument and set it to either `"h5"` or `"tf"`. If you don't specify this argument, the format will be determined by the name you have passed. If the name has the `.h5` suffix, it will be saved in keras, otherwise in the `SavedModel` format.

Anyway, since you have specified suffix `hd5` instead of `h5`, it will be saved in SavedModel format.

You can simply load them in the same way you have saved them.

```
model.save_weights("model.h5")   #h5 format
model.load_weights("model.h5")
#or
model.save_weights("mymodel")    #SavedModel format
model.load_weights("mymodel")
```